# Input as parameter of function

Tags: python

I'm really sorry I'm really new to this. I'm wrote a script for a 'robot' that adds one to a user response, but my code does not run. I'm really new and wondered if anybody could help me understand what I'm doing wrong

```
import time

print("hello, I am the addition bot, I add one to any number you know")
time.sleep(0.7)

print("Quick!")
time.sleep(0.2)

print("My boss is coming, please give me a number!")
time.sleep(0.4)

print("Quick!")
time.sleep(1)

def addOneTo(number):
    return number + 1

oldNumber = input()

print(addOneTo(oldNumber))
```

Comment: When you say "but my code does not run", what did happen vs. what did you expect to happen (see [mcve])? Also which python version are you using?

Comment: When asking for debugging help, it's a good idea to explain what you are trying to do _and_ what problems you are facing. "My code doesn't run" is too generic. That being said, `int(input())` is your solution.

Answer (score 1):

`input()` returns a string, you need to convert it to an `int`

```
def addOneTo(number):
    return int(number) + 1
```

---

You may want to ask the user to type a number, i.e.:

```
input("Please type a number: ")
```

Comment: I think it's better to convert it directly after input: `int(input(...))`. But the conversion is only necessary in python3. For python2 the original code should work as expected.